# How do i ask shadow in Aframe

Tags: three.js, aframe, shadow

[image]

[image]

I use Aframejs but, shadow is not working.
shadow is cut off.
How to work....

this is example
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/noisy-celestial-abrosaurus?path=index.html%3A15%3A30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shadows are generated with the help of an internal camera, which corresponds to the area affected by the light.

You can visualize it with a `light` property called `shadowCameraVisible`. In your case, You should see something like this:

[image]

See how the box is partially outside of the yellow boundary? That explains why the shadow is suddenly cut off. You need to adjust the camera properties to envelop the entire scene:

```
light="type:directional;
       color:#ffffff;
       intensity:1;
       castShadow:true;
       shadowCameraTop:    10;
       shadowCameraRight:  10;
       shadowCameraLeft:  -10"
```

[glitch here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/stack-69401182?path=index.html%3A25%3A19)

Comment: "You need to adjust the camera properties to envelop the entire scene" What mean this? I add shadowCameraTop... add. but not working. please ㅠㅠ    
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/noisy-celestial-abrosaurus?path=index.html%3A32%3A7

Comment: @youngnam sorry, my typo, the left one should be negative, i've added a glitch

Comment: You are a really great person!!

Comment: @youngnam if you don't have any further questions feel free to mark the answer